# KDB: select and round off each row

Tags: kdb

I created my own function of round off:

```
.q.rnd:{$[x < 0; -1; 1] * floor abs[x] + 0.5}
```

I have a table Test with a string column of COL

```
select  "F"$(COL) from Test

24549.18741328
48939.50717263
-274853.33568872
-24549.18741328
298753.62574861
84822.70074144
-7468840.64371524
117944.21228603
-117944.21228603
7468840.64371524
-7468840.64371524
```

I want to derive a table that would round-off the records in Test

One would think that the statement below would work. But it does not.

```
select .q.rnd "F"$(COL) from Test
```

I get the error "type". So how do I round off the records?

Comment: `$` is scalar conditional, but `?` is vector conditional. If you just used that, it would work.

Comment: Also: `?[x<0;-1;x>0;1;0]` is called `signum x`

Comment: Also: Don't name things beginning with `.q`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result if the if-else conditional must be an atomic boolean. When you run .q.rnd on a column, you are operating on a list and `x<0` is going to return a list of booleans, not an atom. The vector conditional is `?`

Nonetheless, it looks like you want a resulting integer/long anyway, so just use parse here

```
q)t:([]string (10?-1 1)*10?10000f)
q)select  "F"$x from t
x
-------------------
4123.1701336801052
-9877.8444156050682
-3867.3530425876379
7267.8099689073861
4046.5459413826466
-8355.0649625249207
6427.3701561614871
-5830.2619284950197
1424.9352994374931
-9149.8820902779698
q)select  "j"$"F"$x from t
x
-----
4123
-9878
-3867
7268
4047
-8355
6427
-5830
1425
-9150
```

Comment: `floor` is faster than `"j"$`

Comment: `floor` is faster than `"j"$` but `"j"$` is faster than `signum[x]*floor abs[x]+.5` which is the comparable operation

Comment: In other words `"j"$` has implicit rounding to nearest

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Sean's said, if you wanted to use your function as well you could use `each` which will apply `.q.rnd` to each item in the list.

```
q)select .q.rnd each "F"$x from t
x
-----
-3928
5171
5160
-4067
-1781
3018
-7850
5347
-7112
-4116
```

but using `select "F"$x from t` is better as it is vectorised.

```
q)\t:1000 select "j"$"F"$x from t
22
q)\t:1000 select .q.rnd each "F"$x from t
33
```

Also it should be noted that the .q namespace isn't necessary and is "reserved for kx use". A lot of the default q functions are in the `.q` namespace and there's always a chance future kdb updates could add a `.q.rnd` that has different behaviour and will break any code where you have used your function in.